# How can I set a unique indentifier on HTML gadgets, when I can't use ID and need to reference the gadget repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, instance, uniqueidentifier

I'm using a plugin (called [renderJs](http://renderjs.org/)) that allows to build HTML pages from reusable gadgets (HTML5 mashups). By default a gadget will look something like this:

```
<div id="header"
  data-gadget-module="header"
  data-gadget="html/modules/header.html"></div>
```

The plugin keeps an index of all gadgets, making invidiual gadgets accessible through the `id=header"`, under which the gadget is stored in the gadgetIndex.

My problem is, I'm using this along with [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), so I'm no friend of using `id-attributes` especially since I want to instantiate and re-use certain gadgets (like the above, which should go on every page).

I have checked instantiation inside **JQM** and **jQueryUI** (both using the [jQuery UI widget factory](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/)) which among other things assigns every widget instance a unique `UUID`.

**My question**:
How would I best set a unique indentifier on resuable gadgtes, if these have to be referenced often?

I could just assign a running counter on every gadget I'm creating and assign that somewhere on a gadget-proto-object, but since I will need to reference gadgets by UUID a lot and also have to manage gadget `state` through URLs (= all gadgets of a page might end up in a URL), I'm wondering what's the best way to label and identify gadgets if I can't use ids?

Comment: you can create your own widgets in jQueryUI with widget factory http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/ widgets use a uuid that is basically just a counter.

Comment: timestamp would be unique and URL friendly (if plain number). So that's good. Still thinking how easy to access this will be... regarding creating own widgets: I thought about that, too, but am still a little reluctant, because I'm looking at a lot of gadgets and object overhead. So let's see what else comes up. Thanks so far.

Comment: anyway even plain jQuery has an undocumented uuid property. you can get the value and increase it with `$.uuid++`

Comment: also nice. Please make an answer, so I can check

Comment: oops, looks like it's gone from jQuery Core